# How to avoid long switch statements? C++

Tags: c++, performance, switch-statement

I am working on a "dictionary" for my class. I have an int array called `NumOfWordsInFile[]` where `NumOfWordsInFile[0]` corresponds to how many words are in A.txt and `NumOfWordsInFile[25]` corresponds to Z.txt

As it is now I have a huge switch for the 26 different conditions of letters. I have a function called `AddWord(string word)`. AddWord gets the first letter of the word passed to it and inserts it into the appropriate .txt file. Now here is the problem. Everytime a word is added to A.txt I must increment `NumOfWordsInFile[0]` by 1. The only way I can think of to do this is with these huge switches. I also have a deleteWord function which conversely decrements `NumOfWordsInFile[]` if the word is deleted. Now I dont want to have two 26 case swithes but the problem is I dont know how else to do it. Now I could just do the same thing for the delete function but I really dont want to have hundreds of more lines of code to go through. Is there a better way to do this?

Sample of the switch in the `AddWord` function:

```
case 'w':
    if (numOfWordsInFile[22] < maxWordsPerFile) {
        fout.open(fileName.data(), ios::app);
        fout << word << " " << endl;
        numOfWordsInFile[22]++;
        if (totalWordsInDict < maxWordsInDict) {
            totalWordsInDict++;
        }
        return(Dictionary::success);
    } else {
        return(Dictionary::failure);
    }

case 'x':
    if (numOfWordsInFile[23] < maxWordsPerFile) {
        fout.open(fileName.data(),ios::app);
        fout << word << " " << endl;
        numOfWordsInFile[23]++;
        if (totalWordsInDict < maxWordsInDict) {
            totalWordsInDict++;
        }
        return(Dictionary::success);
    } else {
        return(Dictionary::failure);
    }
```

Delete function.

```
bool Dictionary::DeleteAWord(string word)
{
    ofstream fout;
    ifstream fin;
    string x;
    string fileName="#.txt";
    int count=0;
    vector <string> words;
    bool deleted=false;

    fileName[0]=toupper(word[0]);
    fin.open(fileName.data()); //makes the file depending on the first letter of the argument "word"

    while (fin >> x)
    {
        words.push_back(x);
        count++;//number of elements in vector
    }
    if (SearchForWord(x))
    {
        for ( ;count > 0; count--)
        {
            if (words[count-1] == word)
            {
                // cout << "Found word " << word << " during search, now deleting" << endl;
                words.erase(words.begin()+(count-1));
                deleted = true;

                /*
                    This clearly doesn't work and is what I need help with, I know why it
                    doesn't work but I don't know how to make it better than having another
                    huge switch.
                */
                numOfWordsInFile[toupper(word[0])]--;
                /*

                */

                totalWordsInDict--;
                fin.close();
            }
        }

        if (deleted)
        {
            fout.open(fileName.data());
            for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++)
                fout << words[i] << endl;
            return(Dictionary::success);
        }
        return(Dictionary::failure);
    }
    return(Dictionary::failure);
}
```

Comment: You have your answer. Pretty much everyone agrees (For good reason) on using the contiguous layout of the letters a-z to accomplish what you want. As long as you're only using English characters (as RedX pointed out), this is the best solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chars are basically numbers. 'a' is 97, 'b' is 98 and so on.
The easiest way is to simply replace every `numOfWordsInFile[n]` with `numOfWordsInFile[current_char - 'a']` and the whole code repeated for each case may reside in a function, like this:

```
   int AddWord(char current_char) {
    if(numOfWordsInFile[current_char - 'a']<maxWordsPerFile){
     fout.open(fileName.data(),ios::app);
     fout<<word<<" "<<endl;
     numOfWordsInFile[current_char - 'a']++;
      if(totalWordsInDict<maxWordsInDict){
       totalWordsInDict++;
     }
     return(Dictionary::success);
    }else{
     return(Dictionary::failure);
    }
   }
```

For more general solutions read about hash maps and function pointers (when, for instance, for each char you might want to assign a different function.

Answer (score 7):

Just taking a very quick look, it seems like you're using the position of the letter in the alphabet to do stuff.

You could replace all your switch statements with one statement that looks like:

```
int letter = (int)(ActualLetter - 'a');

if(numOfWordsInFile[letter]<maxWordsPerFile){
 fout.open(fileName.data(),ios::app);
 fout<<word<<" "<<endl;
 numOfWordsInFile[letter]++;
 if(totalWordsInDict<maxWordsInDict){
   totalWordsInDict++;
 }
 return(Dictionary::success);
}else{
 return(Dictionary::failure);
}
```

ActualLetter is something like, 'a', for example.

On a related note, in the future if you actually have large switch statements, consider encapsulating the code in functions:

```
switch (letter)
{
    case 'a':
      LetterA();
      break;

    case 'b':
      LetterB();
      break;

    ...
}
```

Or even better, you can use polymorphism to have C++ dispatch to the method you want based on the specific derived class:

```
class BaseLetter
{
   ...
public:
   virtual void DoStuff() = 0;
};

class LetterA : public BaseLetter
{
public:
   void DoStuff();
};

class LetterB : public BaseLetter
{
public:
    void DoStuff();
};

void Foo(BaseLetter *letter)
{
    // Use dynamic dispatch to figure out what to do
    letter->DoStuff();
}
```

Just note, dynamic dispatch does have a (slight) performance hit, and the above is a very bad place to actually use it. The solution I, RedX, and others have posted is much better suited to your specific example.

Comment: And in cases where you decide to add extra characters (such as the digits) then you just have to replace the first line with a function that takes a character and returns an index number.

Comment: @swetstrup: Exactly. This is a perfect example of Don't Repeat Yourself.

Answer (score 6):

In most practical character encodings that you're likely to encounter whilst using C or C++, `'a'` to `'z'` are contiguous, so you can get the array index to use simply by doing `(c - 'a')`, where `c` is the `char` you're looking at.

Comment: There is a serious probability that your bank account and your insurance record are stored with an encoding where English alphabet letters are NOT contiguous (EBCDIC). However those systems are most probably programmed in COBOL...

Comment: @6502: That's not a problem, as long as your array has size ('z'-'a'+1). You'll just have a few unused entries in the middle. All sane character encodings have `z` > `a`.

Comment: @MSalters: True. My comment was simply about the word "all practical"... ignoring an encoding in which a serious percentage of business computing is done today is not in my opinion correct. The solution is ok (and I didn't post one because this was present), but the comment on characters encoding is not. Probably adding "on systems programmed in C" would make it better... AFAIK normally EBCDIC machines are programmed with other languages (e.g. they've troubles with '{').

Answer (score 6):

```
struct FileInfo {
  int NumWords;
  std::string Filename;
};

std::map<char, FileInfo> TheFiles; 

FileInfo & FI = TheFiles[letter];
// Work with FI.NumWords and FI.Filename
```

Alternatively:

```
std::vector<FileInfo> TheFiles;
FileInfo & FI = TheFiles[std::tolower(Letter) - 'a'];
```

Comment: At last a sane response: the simplest data structure for the task is *not* defined by how simple the data structure is, but by how simple the interactions (for this task) are. Shun the representation, focus on the methods available.

Comment: @Matthieu M. I wish. But the quest for "efficiency" and "cleverness" seems to overrule everything the first years of any programmers career.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(numOfWordsInFile[letter - 'A']<maxWordsPerFile){
 fout.open(fileName.data(),ios::app);
 fout<<word<<" "<<endl;
 numOfWordsInFile[letter - 'A']++;
 if(totalWordsInDict<maxWordsInDict){
   totalWordsInDict++;
 }
 return(Dictionary::success);
}else{
 return(Dictionary::failure);
}
```

This will only work if you only have english letter in your use-case.

Answer (score 2):

Single characters in C++ are really just numbers corresponding to their ASCII values.  You can subtract letters from each other to get numerical values.  So if `word[0]` contains the letter A, then `word[0] - 'A'` will be `0`.

So you can index your `numOfWordsInFile` array directly, and you won't need a switch at all: `numOfWordsInFiled[word[0] - 'A']`.

Note that `'A' and 'a'` have different numeric values, so you'll have to do some extra work if you're mixing upper and lower case.

Answer (score 1):

If your file is A.txt, let your array index be `'A' - 'A'` (= 0), if the file is B.txt, let the array index be `'B' - 'A'` (= 1), etc.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how portable you want to be, or how
internationalized.  If you can afford to ignore the possibility
that the first letter might be an accented character, and assume
that you're never going to have run on a mainframe, or anywhere
else that uses EBCDIC, then you can convert the first letter to
a specific case, and subtract 'a' or 'A' (depending on the case)
from it to obtain the index.  The C++ standard doesn't guarantee
that the letters are contiguous however, and they aren't in
EBCDIC, nor in any of the encodings which support accented
characters.  At the very least, you'll have to test that the
first character is a letter, of course.

Handling the internationalization issue is difficult, since
there is no one generally used encoding, and some of the
encodings are multibyte.  For the single byte encodings, it's
fairly straight foreward to use a mapping table; a table with
256 entries, indexed by the first letter (cast to unsigned
char), which returns the index into your table.  For multibyte
encodings, like UTF-8, the issue is more complicated: you can
translate the initial character in a UTF-8 sequence to an int,
but you can end up with values around a million or more, and you
don't want a table with a million entries (most of which are
completely irrelevant.  One simple solution might be to add
a 27th entry for "other".  (This would also catch "words" like
"2nd".)

A very portable way to do this would be:

```
int mappingTable[256];

std::fill_n(mappingTable, 256, 26);
static char const upper[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ;
static char const lower[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz;
for (int i = 0; i < 26; ++ i) {
    mappingTable[upper[i]] = i;
    mappingTable[lower[i]] = i;
}
```

Just don't forget to cast the initial character to unsigned char
before indexing.